# Understaing Abstract types

Tags: scala, types, abstract-type

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Base {
  type T
  def myMethod: T
}

abstract class B extends Base {
  type T <: String
}

abstract class C extends Base {
  type T <: Int
}
```

Now, if i write this:

```
class Test{
    self: B with C => 
    // do sth with myMethod
}
```

myMethod will result in sth of type Int. If, on the other hand, I write this:

```
class Test{
    self: C with B => 
    // do sth with myMethod
}
```

I will get type String. Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can! It's [a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7255)! And it's the result of "a fundamental problem in Scala's type system" according to Martin Odersky himself (see the comments on that issue for discussion, and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330848/334519) from earlier this morning).